# Resolving this error: "cannot transform sfc object with missing crs"

Tags: geospatial, r-sf

I am attempting to outline a specific grouping of census tracts over entire US states.

This is the code I am attempting to run:

```
sf_states <- sf::st_as_sf(fifty_states, coords = c("long", "lat")) %>%
  group_by(id, piece) %>%
  summarize(do_union = FALSE) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  ungroup()

illinois <- sf_states %>%
  filter(id == "illinois")

arlington.crs <- arlington.test %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)

ggplot() +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_sf(data = illinois) +
  geom_sf(data = arlington.crs, col = "green", alpha = 0, size = 2)
```

The `arlington.test` data is coming from the `tidycensus` package and includes the associated geometry for each census tract.

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Error in st_transform.sfc(st_geometry(x), crs, ...) : 
  cannot transform sfc object with missing crs
```

I tried dozens of different answers I have come across on StackOverflow and nothing seems to make this work.

What makes it even more strange is that I can run the two `geom_sf` functions with ggplot separately, and they plot just fine.

The error only occurs when I attempt to run them together, as shown in the included `ggplot` code above.

Any other thoughts/ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Edit (to answer the question below):

```
> sf::st_crs(arlington.test)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: NAD83 
  wkt:
GEOGCRS["NAD83",
    DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
        ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4269]]
>
```

Comment: I just made an edit to the original post to include that information (easier to read there than posting it into a comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `arlington.test` object seems to be in [EPSG:4269](https://epsg.io/4269); you attempted to override it to WGS 84 via `sf::st_set_crs(4326)`. Are you certain you did not mean `sf::st_transform(4326)`?

The set crs is best reserved for cases you are certain the CRS is malformed / incorrect (it can happen when the `*.prj` gets lost from your `*.shp` shapefile). This is not a typical use case for `{tidycensus}` data.

To change projection from one known CRS to another `sf::st_transform()` works the best.

Answer (score 0):

The function polygon_from_extent() seems to be deprecated and loses CRS information. You can write your own function to solve this and create a polygon with CRS:

```
# Function to replace 'polygon_from_extent()'
my_polygon_from_extent <- function(x, my_crs){
  x <- FedData:::template_to_sf(x)
  sf::st_crs(x)<-my_crs
  x <- sf:::st_bbox(x)
  x <- sf:::st_as_sfc(x)
  return(x)
}

# Polygon shape you want to build
my_extent <- raster::extent(
  as.numeric(
    sf::st_bbox(dat)[c("xmin","xmax","ymin","ymax")] +
      c(-.05,.05,-.05,.05)
  )
)

# Assign appropriate CRS
my_polygon <- my_polygon_from_extent(my_extent, 4326)
```